# How to set environment variable to machine in c#

Tags: c#, registry

I want's to store sql server name to system Environment variables and get when it needed;

i tried this:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Varname","VarVal",EnvironmnetVariableTarget.Machine);
```

But it shows an error:

> Requested Registry Access Not Allowed
>
> Called Security Exception....

What to do?

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes(v=vs.110).aspx) for that method. your app does not have the required permissions for that operation.

Comment: SO HOW CAN I PERMIT IT

Comment: @morihardev take a look at my answer **:|**

Comment: See the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator) by @Adola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**. You will need to get the required access from Windows. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator) post about getting the right privilege.

Comment: @morihardev Happy to help!